# How can I count unique clicks across jobs for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I store link performance attributed to different categories in a `sent` table like this...

```
CREATE TABLE sent (
  customer_id INT,
  jobId INT,
  category VARCHAR(100),
  timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I am trying to create a query that can show me the customer_id's across the Y axis and the different categories across the X axix. What complicates this is that I only want count a click for every unique Job ID. I have attempted it using the query below but this is on just one category. The categories I want to search against are fixed (around 10 in total) and wanted to know how I can do this in the most efficient way. The table could have MILLIONS of records.

```
SELECT customer_id, count(customer_id) as unique_clicks_discovery
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, jobId, COUNT(*) as discovery_clicks_unique
  FROM sent
  WHERE category = 'discovery'
  GROUP BY customer_id, jobId
) as discovery_click_roundup
GROUP BY customer_id
```

**EDIT:**
Here are the expected results, please refer to the fiddle to see the data.

```
ACCOUNT ID    |   DISCOVER UNIQUE CLICKS  |  PURCHASE UNIQUE CLICKS
--------------------------------------------------------------------
101           |   3                       |  3
102           |   1                       |  1
103           |   1                       |  1
104           |   1                       |  2
```

**EDIT 2:**
With sample data used:

```
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 202, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 203, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 203, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 203, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (102, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (102, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (103, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (103, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (104, 201, 'discovery');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 202, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 203, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 203, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 203, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (101, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (102, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (102, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (103, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (103, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (104, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (104, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (104, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (104, 202, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (103, 201, 'purchase');
INSERT INTO sent (customer_id, jobId, category) VALUES (103, 201, 'purchase');
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayUQN16KggYs91pqs1fBs/2) (including sample data)

Comment: update your question and add also your expected  result  ..

Comment: it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  What does it mean to count a click for every unique job id?  If the same job id appears in multiple categories, does it count towards each category or just one?

Comment: @scaisEdge updated

Comment: @MK. Yes, I only want to count 1 for each click on a category by Job ID. If the the same Job ID has clicks in different categories they should be counted in separate columns as shown in my example.

Comment: Can you put sample data considering your expected output?

Comment: @mkRabbani done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* here:

```
SELECT customer_id
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE category WHEN 'discovery' THEN jobId END) AS unique_clicks_discovery
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE category WHEN 'purchase'  THEN jobId END) AS unique_clicks_purchase
FROM sent
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

You will have to append one `COUNT(..)` line per category.

Result:

```
| customer_id | unique_clicks_discovery | unique_clicks_purchase |
| ----------- | ----------------------- | ---------------------- |
| 101         | 3                       | 3                      |
| 102         | 1                       | 1                      |
| 103         | 1                       | 1                      |
| 104         | 1                       | 2                      |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mytptQup4rpAAE3qJ1PAZb/0)

Comment: @MK. DISTINCT will be applied to what is returned from the CASE statement. I could also write it as `COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE category WHEN 'discovery' THEN jobId END)) `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id, 
sum(case when category = 'discovery' then cnt else 0 end) discovery,
sum(case when category = 'purchase' then cnt else 0 end) purchase
FROM (
  SELECT category, customer_id, COUNT(distinct jobid) cnt
  FROM sent
  GROUP BY category, customer_id
) t
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Comment: How or why does this work? Where is the explainment?